# .net Web API. How to retrieve user properties (user Id) from access token? Request handler code based on current user/token

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization, access-token

Let's say you have a .net Web API server for a user based application. The user logs into the application with a username and password which is sent to the server and the app is given an access token back.

Now the app wants to show pieces of user information (stored on the server in a DB). So it makes the http request to server and includes the access token in the header.

How do you restrict that the server will only send back to the application the relevent information for that particular user and no one else's information.

Is there a way, when I receive their username and password and am creating a token to send back, to associate their userId with that token? So now when I get a request to something like /GetUserFoodPreferences, I can just get the userId from the token and query my db based on that id.

Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 11):

Storing the userid, or some other kind of id connected to that user in a cookie would be the most common way. You can then inspect that cookie (Request.Cookies["name"];) for the id to confirm the user.

EDIT: If of course you are using the API Controller and authenticating your user correctly you can use:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

NOTE : don't forget to `import Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` library.

Comment: is GetUserId() some custome method you write yourself? I am seeing that IIDentity has AuthenticationType, IsAuthenticated, and Name.

Comment: How is it you are authenticating the user?

Comment: The get id method comes as part of MVC in the following library Microsoft.AspNet.Identity however its worth checking what authentication provider / method you are using.

Comment: Yeah that method works when i import Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.

Comment: I am just using the default authentication that a web api project comes with.

Comment: Can I add my own custom fields to IIdentity? Basically I have a userId for my own User entity. I want to assign this id to a token when the token is requested.

Comment: The Identity only get a getter and no setter, you can however set the User property which is of type IPricipal, however i would recommend leaving it how it is. Can you confirm what authentication method you are using, e.g is this Form authentication?

Comment: OAuth. ApplicationOAuthProvider.

Comment: So lets say I have /GetTopTenRecipes but I only want to send data back to that request if the user sending the request meets some other condition (has 4 or more submitted recipes lets say). Should that checking logic be in the RecipeController.GetTopTenRecipes method? Using Identity User fields to perform additional  queries and logical checks?

Comment: Yes from what you have written there that makes sense to me. Please also see this related question regarding getting the UserId for OAuth.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

In your project, go to `Providers/ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs`, search the method `public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)`, and add this line after the `foreach`:

```
context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add ("userID" context.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Your code would look like:

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
    {
        context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
    }

    context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add("userID",context.Identity.GetUserId());

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

Comment: How do you retrieve from the token once you've added it?

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar issue which I solve by creating a customized OAuthProvider.

```
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private readonly IYourLoginLogic _loginLogic;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public ApplicationOAuthProvider(IYourLoginLogic loginLogic)
    {
        _loginLogic = loginLogic;
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Login the user with username and password.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext</param>
    /// <returns>Not used</returns>
    public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        bool loginRst = _loginLogic.Login(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if(!loginRst)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
        }
        else
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));
            context.Validated(identity);
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```

This way, the username will be included in the token returned to client. When the client send the request back with the token, you can get the username from the request's context as below:

```
public class CustomizedAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);

        string username = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;
        // do something with the username
    }
}
```

You will need to use the CustomizedAuthrize attribute for your controllers or actions you want to protect.

In my case, it is like:

```
[CustomizedAuthorize]
public sealed class MyController : ApiController {......}
```